# Integrating Wordpress account and CiviCRM contact details self-maintenance

Tags: wordpress, contacts, user-account

Still pretty new to CiviCRM so apologies if I am on the totally wrong track here.

We are embedding profiles into Wordpress pages to allow users to self-administer their contact details. To do this they need to be logged in as wordpress users. Would also like to be able to include "change password" as one of the fields they could change when administering their contact details ***without*** sending the user into the wordpress dashboard/backend.

Has anyone tackled this by means of a plugin or other mechanism that might easily allow placement of wordpress account administration alongside civicrm profile details? Or am I stuck dealing with all the WP stuff using plugins/hooks for it separately from the CiviCRM data.

Put another way - I never want an end user to see the "back end" of either WP dashboard or CiviCRM interface, just keep them on the website itself. How do I do this? Make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way we have done this is with a WP plugin.  WP User Front end allows editing of a WP user's profile from the front end. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/.

If you are on CiviCRM 4.6.3 you can mix WordPress and CiviCRM content on the same page, so two shortcodes could be used. While I have not tried this, it may be possible.

I also recommend https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/  for keeping key data in sync between WP and CiviCRM (this requires CiviCRM 4.6)

Comment: nice, we haven't done the jump to 4.6.x yet but I had read there was new functionality for WP hooks, just hadn't groked yet how this would come into play. The scenario you describe above sounds like it wil lwork great, appreciate it!